# How to get some information from remote machine by using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

First of all, sorry for dummy question.

I would like to get distribution information from remote target by using following sample code under shell script. My local machine is Ubuntu16.04 and remote target is Ubuntu20.04(192.168.100.15). However, when I run shell script, the $distribution value is ubuntu16.04.

Why the value is not Ubuntu20.04? and How should I modify my code correctly?

```
ssh root@192.168.100.15 "distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo ) && echo $distribution"
```

Comment: There is only an empty `echo` inside the `$()`. This does not give `ubuntu16.04`, it gives a blank line.

Comment: The immediate error is that sourcing a file in a subprocess discards the results as soon as the subprocess exits. The entire `distribution` variable seems useless here.

Comment: do you want your **local variable** `distribution` to have the data from the remote machine?

Comment: @Thomas Because I run this code under shell script with -x flag and the output shows $distribution value is Ubuntu16.04

Comment: You have edited the question to show double quotes instead of single quotes. That makes all the difference: `$()` and `$distribution` are evaluated on the local machine now. That still doesn't cause it to show `ubuntu16.04` unless `$distribution` is already set to that value in your current shell before you even ran this command.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of `/etc/os-release` to find out which variables are available, then `echo` one of those. For example:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.100.15 '. /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME'
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

If you want to populate the `distribution` variable on your *local* machine, you need to use the `$(...)` construct locally:

```
$ distribution=$(ssh root@192.168.100.15 '. /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME')
$ echo $distribution
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

By the way, giving ssh access to the `root` user is [frowned upon nowadays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it). And using `root` in this case is entirely unneccesary anyway, because `/etc/os-release` is world-readable to any user.

Comment: Thanks for advice about ssh access by using root. Actually, because I have copy ssh public key into target machine and also keep PermitRootLogin prohibit-password.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsb_release`:

```
ssh root@192.168.100.15 'lsb_release -ds'
```

LSB means [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base). The command should be available on every Linux system.